# pass @selector to my UIbutton but click event not response

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

my code ：

```
 - (void)showWithStatus:(NSString *)status barColor:(UIColor*)barColor textColor:(UIColor*)textColor click:(SEL)click{
    if(!self.superview)
        [self.overlayWindow addSubview:self];
    [self.overlayWindow setHidden:NO];
    [self.topBar setHidden:NO];
    self.topBar.backgroundColor = barColor;
    NSString *labelText = status;
    CGRect labelRect = CGRectZero;
    CGFloat stringWidth = 0;
    CGFloat stringHeight = 0;
    if(labelText) {
        CGSize stringSize = [labelText sizeWithFont:self.stringLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.topBar.frame.size.width, self.topBar.frame.size.height)];
        stringWidth = stringSize.width;
        stringHeight = stringSize.height;

        labelRect = CGRectMake((self.topBar.frame.size.width / 2) - (stringWidth / 2), 0, stringWidth, stringHeight);
    }
    self.stringLabel.frame = labelRect;
    self.stringLabel.alpha = 0.0;
    self.stringLabel.hidden = NO;
    self.stringLabel.text = labelText;
    self.stringLabel.textColor = textColor;

    clickBn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:self.stringLabel.frame];
    clickBn.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    [clickBn addTarget:self action:click forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if(!clickBn.superview)
        [self.topBar addSubview:clickBn];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        self.stringLabel.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
//    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

and call this method:

```
 - (IBAction)successButtonPressed:(id)sender {
[KGStatusBar showSuccessWithStatus:@"Successfully synced" click:@selector(clickBn)];
 }


 - (void)clickBn {
NSLog(@"sss");
 [KGStatusBar dismiss];
}
```

the  NSLog(@"sss") not show. i want to pass a method to UIButton of customView ,but when i click the UIbutton not respond.

Comment: what is `KGStatusBar`, a class? if so the problem is that you are calling an instance method from a class

Comment: yes ,you are right. it is KGStatusBar,and i want to custom click event.

Comment: you have to make the call from an instance variable, not from the class it self, it is weird that the compiler do not warn you about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an delegate in control in .h file before `@interface` and after header files.

```
@protocol YourControlDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) delegateMethod;

@end
```

in `@interface`

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) id <YourControlDelegate> yourdelegate;
```

in `.m @synthesize` the `yourdelegate`.

in button click action call `[self.yourdelegate delegateMethod]`;

In your `ViewController` add `YourControlDelegate` like as follow

```
@interface YourVC : UIViewController <YourControlDelegate>
```

in `.m` implement the `delegate` method

```
-(void) delegateMethod
{
    //you code.
}
```

Here when you click the button the `delegateMethod` in `viewController` will be get called.

Answer (score 0):

this is your clickBn method right?

```
- (void)clickBn {
NSLog(@"sss");
 [KGStatusBar dismiss];
}

now what you doing in action? action:click??
do like following 

clickBn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:self.stringLabel.frame];
    clickBn.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    [clickBn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickBn)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 If you want to call method which is in another class then do like this 
first make object of that class


  ViewController *dvController = [ViewController alloc] init];
   after that [dvController methodName];
do this all in your clickBn method First clickBn method will be called and it will call that another class method which you wanted to call 
 NOTE: you need to import that class in header
```

Comment: i want to send selector to another class

Answer (score 0):

action should be a selector method.

If you want to pass the button as an argument to the method user `:` for example

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
                                         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
   //your code and you can also access the button properties using sender.
}
```

it is preferred. If you don't want to use sender(button) exclude the `:`

Comment: the buttonClicked  method come from control,my button from my custom view.i want to pass the buttonClicked from the control to the View